# Hyperlink not working on popup

Tags: javascript, css, popup, popupwindow

I have a website Here.

There's a pop up window that appears as soon as the page is loaded. However, I'm unable to utilize links in the HTML content.

**Here's the HTML...**

```
<body onload="popup('popUpDiv')">

<div id="blanket" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none">

<a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')" ><img src="images/x.png" /></a>
        <br />
    <h3 style="color: #FFF; padding-left: 10px;">Updates to the AR Toolbox</h3>
            <br />
                <br />
                <div style="width: 350px; height: 300px; text-align: left;">
                <p style="padding-left: 50px; color: #000;">• Check out the new rotating Announcement Board on the AR Toolbox!</p>
                    <br />
                <p style="padding-left: 50px; color: #000;">• Have you seen the new SUO Tour yet? Click <a href="#" target="_blank">here</a> to check it out!</p>                
                    <br />
                <p style="padding-left: 50px; color: #000;">• South University and The Education Foundation Scholarship Committee are now on SharePoint. Click <a href="#" target="_blank"> here!</a></p>
                    <br />
        </div>
</div>
```

When you look at the popup, you'll see all my links are grouped in the upper right corner of the popup window, with the 'X'.

**Here's the CSS for the Popup...**

```
#blanket {
   background-color:#111;
   opacity: 0.65;
   filter: alpha(opacity=65)
   *background:none;
   position:absolute;
   z-index: 9001;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   width:100%;
}

#popUpDiv {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image:url(../images/popup_bg.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;    
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border:5px solid #000;
    z-index: 9002;
}


#popUpDiv a {
    background-image: url(../images/x.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px}
```

I think it lies in the '#popUpDiv a' section, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any ideas?

Edit: Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/tQKX9/)

On the 2nd bullet, you'll see "Click to check it out!" when it should be "Click **here** to check it out!"

On the 3rd bullet, you'll see "Click", when it should be "Click **here**."

But, again, all the the links are bundled up in the top right-hand corner for some reason.

Comment: Could you put it together in a fiddle or something, I don't really understand what you're trying to do

Comment: I have just added a jsfiddle. Sorry about that. I'll do that from now on.

Comment: See the edit above for the jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your response. Looks like you got it figured out. @JaredNewman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of applying the style to `a`, just create a style class and apply that to the `popUpDiv`. Like this...

```
#popUpDiv .close {
    background-image: url(../images/x.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute; 
    top:10px; 
    right:10px
}
```

and apply it to the `popup href`...

```
<a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')" class="close"><img src="images/x.png" /></a>
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO here**](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/PXTfH/1/)

Hope this helps!